# How do you parse the noun phrase 'Even the manager herself'?

Tags: modifiers, noun-phrases

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Pages 438-9) has these subsections under **§13 Peripheral modifiers**:

> **(e) Reflexive pronouns** 
> [7] [*The manager h̲e̲r̲s̲e̲l̲f̲*] *had approved the proposal.*
> In this construction an NP with the form of a reflexive pronoun functions as post-head modifier within a larger NP; it is an external rather than internal modifier in that the immediate constituents of the matrix NP are *the manager* + *herself* (not *the* + *manager herself*). [...]
> **(f) Combinations** 
> An NP may contain more than one peripheral modifier, with multiple layers of embedding: 
> [8] i *Make sure you invite* [*Jill h̲e̲r̲s̲e̲l̲f̲ t̲o̲o̲*]. 
> ii [*E̲v̲e̲n̲ m̲e̲r̲e̲l̲y̲ a formal apology*] *would be acceptable*. 
> iii *After* [*f̲i̲n̲a̲n̲c̲i̲a̲l̲l̲y̲ c̲e̲r̲t̲a̲i̲n̲l̲y̲ the worst crisis this decade*], *the emerging economies will take some time to recover.* 
> The bracketed NP in [i] has the NP *Jill herself* as head and the adverb *too* as peripheral modifier; at the next level, the NP *Jill* is head and the NP *herself* is peripheral modifier. A peripheral modifier is thus in peripheral position (initial or final) in the NP of which it is an immediate constituent, but need not be in peripheral position in a larger NP containing it.

Based on this, I wonder how we should parse the noun phrase 'Even the manager herself' as in [7']: 
[7'] [*E̲v̲e̲n̲ the manager h̲e̲r̲s̲e̲l̲f̲*] *had approved the proposal.*

Here, both *Even* and *herself* are what CGEL calls peripheral modifiers. Here are some parsing options I can think of: 
(1) *E̲v̲e̲n̲* + [*the manager* + *h̲e̲r̲s̲e̲l̲f̲*];
(2) [*E̲v̲e̲n̲* + *the manager*] + *h̲e̲r̲s̲e̲l̲f̲*; or
(3) *E̲v̲e̲n̲* + [*the manager*] + *h̲e̲r̲s̲e̲l̲f̲*

Which is correct? Or is there any other way?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151070/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-how-do-you-parse-the-noun-phrase-even-the-manager); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

The three possibilities being considered are:

1. [Even [[the manager] herself]] had approved the proposal.
2. [[Even [the manager]] herself] had approved the proposal.
3. [[Even] [the manager] [herself]] had approved the proposal.

First, consider that we can replace the NP "the manager" with an NP-coordination:

4. Even the manager and the client themselves had approved the proposal.

We can do the same with "the manager herself":

5. Even the manager herself and the client himself had approved the proposal.

But we *can't* do this with "even the manager":

6. * Even the manager and even the client themselves had approved the proposal.

Coordination is not necessarily a perfect guide to syntactic structure, but, all else being equal, if a sequence of words can be coordinated, we should treat it as a syntactic constituent; certainly none of the kinds of non-basic coordination H&P list apply here (see pp. 1348-1350). So it seems that we should take "the manager herself" to be a constituent, but not "even the manager."

So this counts strongly in favor of analysis (1), "[Even [[the manager] herself]] had approved the proposal."

Comment: I find your bracketing confusing. The NP "even the manager herself" is subject and thus an immediate constituent of the sentence. To analyse it further requires the clarity of a tree, not bracketing.

Comment: Aherm. **[Huddleston & Pullum]don't ever describe any node in a syntax tree as having more than two immediate constituents** <--- Not at all true, I'm afraid. See p. 1278 *the guests [and indeed his family too]*, where they give the NP in brackets **4!** immediate constituents. However, see also the discussion [in section 3.4.2 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.00394.pdf), which is on the fourth page of that doc.

Comment: Nice post so far! (notwithstanding   the H&P binary branching thingy). I've edited your 3rd example, because I think it's clear that that's what you mean (from your 'immediate constituents' comment). If I've stuffed that up, feel free to undo, need it be said :) Now you just need to explain why  (3) is incorrect!

Comment: @Araucaria-Him I've removed the binary branching claim, since the rest of my argument on its own establishes that "the manager herself" is a constituent, which is inconsistent with analysis (3) anyway.

Comment: +1 for trying to stay within the confines of CGEL. And I myself would probably choose (1) instinctively, but I don't fully grasp what you mean when you say "if a sequence of words can be coordinated, we should treat it as a syntactic constituent". Certainly, _even_ is part of the first coordinate in (4) and (5). (6) is unnatural not because _Even the manager_ and _even the client themselves_ are not coordinates, but because repeating _even_ for each coordinates is unnaturally redundant.

Comment: @JK2 On the most obvious reading, the word *themselves* in (4) is referring to the manager and the client together, not to the client in a gender-neutral way. I would prefer *themself* in the latter case); so *themselves* must be modifying the plural NP-coordination "the manager and the client," not the singular NP "the client."

Comment: Likewise, the *even* in (4) applies to both the manager and the client; the relationship between syntactic structure and semantic scope is rarely straightforward, but I find it fairly obvious that *even* is also outside of the coordination, not part of the first coordinate.

Comment: It strikes me as very obvious that (6) is not just redundant but ungrammatical (unless you try to read *themselves* as a gender-neutral "singular they," in which case I at least would expect *themself* instead).

Comment: But see (7) _The manager herself and even the client himself had approved the proposal._ Here, _even the client himself_ is the second coordinate, isn't it?

Comment: @JK2 In that case, yes, it is. But it's hard to read \*"The manager herself and even the client **themselves** had approved the proposal" in the same way, given the use of *themselves* instead of *himself* or *herself* or *themself."

Comment: In the last sentence, you seem to intend _themselves_ to belong to the second coordinate. If so, what's the point of changing _himself_ to _themselves_? What's that got to do with the issue of whether _even_ can be part of a coordinate or not?

Answer (score -6):

Herself is a pronoun and stands in apposition.

OED: **Herself** (pron.):

> **I.1. In apposition to a personal noun (as subject or object) or to a subjective pronoun: that particular female person or animal, etc.; the
> female person in question personally.**
>
> In early use also in apposition to grammatically feminine nouns.
> Occasionally used in relation to a singular noun or pronoun of
> undetermined gender.
>
> OE Ðeos eorðe is geworht, ac heo nis na hyre sylf lif. [My
> translation: This earth is created, but she is not herself life]
> *Ælfric, Homily (Vitellius MS. C.v) in J. C. Pope, Homilies of Ælfric (1967) vol. I. 208*
>
> 1945 She herself was probably more than a little frightened of her own
> sexuality. *N. Streatfeild, Saplings xiv. 224*

Even is an adverb - often an emphatic free modifier:

> **Even** (adv.) **II.8.a. Used to convey that what is being referred to is
> an extreme case in comparison with a weaker or more general one which
> is stated or implied in the adjacent context. Prefixed to the
> particular word, phrase, or clause in which the extremeness of the
> case is expressed.**
>
> 2007 Even the newest New Yorker knows that the furthest eastern border
> of Greenwich Village is Fourth Avenue. *Time Out New York 18 January 24/3*

Comment: I tend not to overlump, and while 'even' here certainly adds emphasis, has a degree of freedom in its distribution, and addresses the mirativity of the manager's adding her endorsement (a sentence qualifier), I'd call it a mirative marker (focus particle).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Mirativity? Does that exist in English? There seems to be no "mirativity" in the 2007 quote. Lumping "focus particles" and "mirativity" together is quite a feat. ;)

Comment: Mirative (broad definition): a device expressing the unexpectedness of an accompanying statement. [[Peterson](https://oxfordre.com/linguistics/display/10.1093/acrefore/9780199384655.001.0001/acrefore-9780199384655-e-497?rskey=NtTvfl#:~:text=Broadly%20defined%2C%20mirativity%20is%20the,event%2C%20or%20activity%20they%20experience.)]. See [Simonin](https://journals.openedition.org/anglophonia/1775).

Comment: So which of the three options is correct?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Emphatic (broad definition) drawing attention to any aspect.

Comment: 'Even' in this usage has the implicature that the focus [the manager] is among the least likely members of the subset (those approving the proposal, superset those making any pronouncement). (And the implicature that _some_ people approved the proposal.)

Comment: 'Broadly defined, mirativity is the linguistic term often used to describe utterances that speakers use to express their surprise at some unexpected state, event, or activity they experience.' Adding 'even' before the subject in 'The manager had approved the proposal.' expresses surprise at the inclusion of this unlikely champion among the subset of supporters. Didn't you read the Simonin article?

Comment: Ah, I see. You have read more into the example than I have.

Comment: @Greybeard The adverb "even" is a focusing modifier. What is so difficult about this?

Comment: @Greybeard "Even" belongs to the word class (POS) adverb and its function here is that of focusing modifier. What could be simpler?

Comment: @Greybeard How can you possibly claim (or imply)  that "herself" is an appositive? It's simply a pronoun functioning here as an emphatic modifier.

Comment: Long quotations form dictionaries almost never constitute answers unless they are embedded in an explanation that shows their relevance to the question.